# I am facing issue in uploading file by using $.ajax()

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I have a page having a TextArea(HTML) and Post Button(HTML) just bellow that Textarea.
On the click of that button I am calling $.ajax() method by which I am calling an appropiate controller action method.There is a  uploader just above the Post Button from where user can upload any file & that file is uploaded to the server by using FormData() class object.The whole flow ofthe code is as follows

1. User enters the text in textarea
2. Upload an attachment file(if required)
3. Then Click on the Post Button
4. A Javascript function is called who then uses FormData() to upload a file with particular key name
5. $.ajax() method is called and it calls controller's action method where I store the file in Session
6. Then again I call $.ajax() which calls controller's another action method which is responsible for adding the text to the database and in this method I retrive file from Session which I store in step 5.

Now the problem is that sometimes action method of step 5 is not called due to which I don't get any attachment file in step 6 action method. Though out of 10 times it is happening 1 time that I post a text with an attachment and that text comes without attachment.Previously I thought there is some caching issue so I decorate the controller's action method with [OutputCacheAttribute(VaryByParam = "*", Duration = 0, NoStore = true)] the scenerio happens in this way Suppose I have posted following 7 text

1. Com1 (With Attachment File “List of UI & Database Objects”)(Uploaded Successfully)
2. Com2(Without Attachment) (Uploaded Successfully)
3. Com3(With Attachment File “List of UI & Database Objects”) ”)(Uploaded Successfully)
4. Com4(Without Attachment) ”)(Uploaded Successfully)
5. Com5(With Attachment File “List of UI & Database Objects”)(Uploaded But Attachment Is Absent)
6. Com6(With Attachment File “List of UI & Database Objects”)(Uploaded Successfully)
7. Com7(With Attachment File “List of UI & Database Objects”)(Uploaded Successfully)

Here Com5 is not uploaded with attachment rest all the comments are uploaded

Comment: Code please.. Without it how do you expect us to help?

Comment: Maybe the problem is that you're using asynchronus AJAX and you didn't store the file at point 6, so you need to wait until the point 5's AJAX process is finished.

Comment: Hi  Fernando Gallego Fernández I agree with your point but can you suggest me how I can implement it by using Jquery.Synchronization by Jquery